# Do I have to use a PS3 controller or can I use Logitech?

Tags: controllers, tomb-raider

I have never used a controller on my pc. Looking for something cheaper than the PS or Xbox. What ones will work on a laptop and are less costly?

Comment: Sorry, we don't do hardware recommendations on Arqade. I recommend checking out [the tour](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/tour) to check out what we're all about.

Comment: It's usually less costly to spend a bit more for a good controller that will last 5 years or more, than to save a few bucks for one that you'll have to replace every 6 months.

Comment: Try hardware recommendations

Comment: Or more over Super User